# MonoTouch DialogViewController TableView fill

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using MonoTouch DialogViewController for a table, but the TableView has a margin around all sides of it by default. The style is set to Grouped.

What's the best way to have the TableView fill the available space, so that it looks like a regular TableView dropped onto a ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Miguel de Icaza, I learned that I needed to set the style of the DialogViewController to UITableViewStyle.Plain to get the filled look that I wanted.